# Using Fluent Bit Modify Filter on Kubernetes properties

Tags: logging, kubernetes, fluent-bit

I'm using Fluent Bit (1.3.11) to collect logs from containers running on k8s. What I would like to do is some basic processing using Fluent Bit Modify filters (i.e. to standardize log level names).

I added two modify filters (see below). The first one is just to verify that modify filters work. It checks if `log` key is present and sets a property if found. That works.
The second modify filter is what I'm actually trying to do. It supposedly rewrites `log_processed.Level` value from `ERR` to `Error` but I couldn't make it actually work. After some experimenting I think that none of the filters that have a condition depending on either `log_processed.*` or `kubernetes.*` properties (added by the kubernetes filter) work.

Is there a recommended/working way to modify logs comming from Kubernetes?

```
 [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               kube.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     kube.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed

        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off

    [FILTER] 
        Name        modify
        Match       kube.*

        Condition   Key_exists log

        Set         my.custom.prop modify-filter-applied

    [FILTER]
        NAME        modify
        Match       kube.*

        Condition   Key_value_equals log_processed.Level ERR

        Set         log_processed.Level Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to utilize a [Lua filter](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/lua) to modify the records.

```
[FILTER]
    Name                lua
    Match               kube.*
    script              levelRewrite.lua
    call                level_rewrite
```

```lua
function level_rewrite(tag, timestamp, record)
    for key, val in pairs(record) do
        if key == "log_processed" then
            if val["level"] == "I" then
                val["level"] = "Info"
                -- return code 2 is supported in Fluent Bit v.1.4.3+
                return 2, timestamp, record
            end
        end
    end

    return 0, 0, 0
end
```